# jQuery position().left, offsetLeft returning hugely different values in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery

Updated for simplicity:
http://jsfiddle.net/vJVcf/5/

///

http://jsfiddle.net/kE6TR/

(the animation happens when hovering on the paragraph)

I have no idea what causes this, but I have narrowed the difference down to the position().left; value - for some reasons webkit and firefox interpret it completely differently.

```
var $plugin = jQuery.sub();
$plugin.fn.animate = function(props, speed, cb) {



    if (typeof(speed) == "function") cb = speed, speed = 500;
    if (typeof(cb) != "function") cb = function() {};
    return $.each(this, function(i, el) {
        el = $(el);

        if (props.float && props.float != el.css("float")) {
            var elem = el.clone().insertBefore(el).addClass('killme'),
            temp = el.position().left;
            el.css('position', 'absolute');
            props.marginLeft = 0;
            props.left = 0;

            el.css({
                marginLeft: temp
            });
        }
        $(this).animate(props, speed, function() {
            $(this).css(props);
            cb();
            el.css({
                marginLeft: -100,
                position: "relative",
                display: "block",
                clear: "both"
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could create a dramatically less complex example? Ideally a static one? Also, your title mentions `offsetLeft`, but I don't see you using it anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps he means, marginLeft?

Comment: Can you explain "no idea what causes this"? What are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: updated the code to make it simpler, http://jsfiddle.net/vJVcf/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're going for, but your jQuery looked unnecessarily complex ... what about replacing it with this? (ex. http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/uGNzA/)

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.eula_animate').each( function(){
        $(this)
            .clone()
            .prependTo(this)
            .addClass('move_me')
            .css({'left': $(this).offset().left });
    });

    $('p').hover( function(){
        $('.move_me').show().animate({'left':20},2000);
    });

});
```

... oh yeah, and add this CSS: `.move_me{ display:none; position:absolute; color:red; }`

Comment: This unfortunately still does not work for me, as I want the words to slide out of the paragraph and align left of the text. this starts them to the right in chrome. I've updated the jfiddle to be easier and more legible.  Thanks :)

Comment: Does exactly that for me. Using Windows 7, all modern browsers. Hmm.